# How do I setup a method to return a DbParameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface I am attempt mock up for unit testing. It has a method that accepts two parameters, name and value and returns a DbParameter to be built from those parameters

```
public interface IDbUnitOfWork {
   DbParameter BuildParameter(string name, object value);
}
```

I am attempting to set up a test case which I can mock up a returned DbParameter and I am having trouble.

```
   unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IDbUnitOfWork>();
   unitOfWorkFactoryMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkFactory>();
   unitOfWorkFactoryMock.Setup(u => u.LoadUnitOfWork()).Returns(new Mock<IDbUnitOfWork>().Object);
   unitOfWorkMock
            .Setup(u => u.BuildParameter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
            .Returns((name, value) => ASDASDASDASD);
```

how can I return a DbParameter populated with passed in parameters or a Mocked up DbParameter?

---

Solution (thanks to Patrick)

```
 unitOfWorkMock
    .Setup(u => u.BuildParameter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns((string name, object value) => Mock.Of<DbParameter>(p=> p.ParameterName == name && p.Value == value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`DbParameter` is abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.aspx) and so can be mocked, I believe this should do the trick:

```
unitOfWorkMock
    .Setup(u => u.BuildParameter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns((name, value) => 
        Mock.Of<DbParameter>(x => x.ParameterName == name && x.Value == value)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Patick! You set me on a new path and I found what my underlying issue was. It ended up being that I needed to specify the data types of name and value. I'm going to update the question and credit you with the answer.

Comment: Ah, yep that makes sense.  Feel free to add your solution as an answer and accept that instead!

Comment: Nah, you answered it.